# Where is the traffic flow direction stored in OSM route data?

Tags: openstreetmap, qgis

I downloaded OSM route data and opened it in QGIS in order to see if traffic flow direction could be displayed (and this is the case). To do so, I just changed the symbology by replacing the simple line symbol by the arrow.

So, I am wondering where this information is stored in the downloaded route data? How is QGIS able to display it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every [way](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way) in OSM has a direction. A way *can* have a [`oneway`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:oneway) tag. If `oneway=yes` is set then traffic can only flow in the direction of the way. If `oneway=-1` is set then traffic can only flow *against* the direction of the way.